# JMeter Loading time showing wrong reading

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am new to Jmeter , actually I was trying to check the loading time taken for each page in my php application. I used highcharts API for the graphs. When clicking on data menu it will list out all the six graphs. I used Blazemeter chrome extension to record the loading time taken for the six graphs. Once loading time is recorded for each graphs i export the file with .jmx extension which is available in Blazemeter and imported in JMeter and started with iteration for one user, two users , five users and ten users. But when i was checking manually the second graph is taking more time for loading , approximately 7 Secs. But in my JMeter, loading time is shown as 0.534Secs for one user. Please anyone help me how to check the loading time for graphs.
with regards,
T.Ragith

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to JavaScript-driven requests in your application, i.e. it uses [AJAX technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/) JMeter doesn't execute JavaScript found in the webpage, you need to either find a way to kick off the same requests real browsers do or switch to real browsers for your load testing via [JMeter WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler).